# JScrollPane component doesn't appear

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jlist

I am trying to add a JList to my JPanel as it is stated by the following source code but it's not working :

```
    public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    UIManager.setLookAndFeel( UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName() );

    DefaultListModel<String> defListPlayers = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    defListPlayers.addElement("Player 1");
    defListPlayers.addElement("Player 2");

    JList<String> listPlayers = new JList<String>(defListPlayers);
    listPlayers.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    listPlayers.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    listPlayers.setVisibleRowCount(10);


    JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(listPlayers);
    scroller.setViewportBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
    scroller.revalidate();

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(scroller);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame;
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().repaint();

    }
   }
```

Any idea please why and what to do?

Comment: use a [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"? I guess want to also remove `scroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 10));`.

Comment: @LuxxMiner : I removed that line, still not working

Comment: Post a [mcve] for better help sooner

Comment: The problem in my case is that the JScrollPane or let's say the JList component doesn't appear in my JFrame
Any concrete example of how to use a layout manager to solve my problem please ?

Comment: @sasuke: if you posted your [mcve], we can show you a proper example with **your** code. Otherwise your request makes no sense, because it all depends on the context of **your** code. You can search this site for many examples of correct use of a scroll pane, and try them out. First and foremost, though, remove all `setBounds(...)` and all null layouts from your code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : Thanks for your reply, I adjusted the source code as instructed. Still my players JList doesn't appear!

Comment: After I changed `new JFrame;` to `new JFrame("My Frame");` and added imports, your code ran fine for me, and the JScrollPane appears.

Comment: Why would that not work on my machine ?!! I am using jdk 1.7 btw

Comment: Make sure you're running the correct class for one.

Comment: Works for me.  Are you running the code within the context of the EDT? See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details